# iPhone modal loading view

Tags: iphone, loading, uiactivityindicatorview

I was wondering if this loading screen is a preset or a custom build view.

[image]

If it is a preset, how can I add this to a view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you have all you need : [UIActivityIndicatorView or similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2297034/uiactivityindicatorview-or-similar)